# Limits and sandwich rule with non continuous functions

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

**For the following function, find L ∈ ℝ such that g(x) tents to L as x tends to infinity. Prove that lim g(x) -> L by using the sandwich rule.**

**g: (0,∞) -> ℝ, x->g(x): = (1/x if x ∈ ℕ), (0 otherwise)**

I'm pretty sure the limit of this is 0, but the fact that it's not continuous and is 1/x only in the natural numbers is throwing me off.

The sandwich rule basically says if f,g,h are functions from X to ℝ, f(x)≤g(x)≤h(x) and f(x) and h(x) tend to L as x tends to infinity, then g(x) also tends to L as x tends to infinity.

So basically I need to find a function less than g for f(x) and a function greater than g for h(x) that both have the limit 0 (if this is the correct limit) but I am unsure of what function to choose as g is not continuous.

Comment: Plus and minus $\frac1x$ ?

Comment: Would this suffice? I thought about using -1/x for f, but was unsure about using 1/x for h because 1/x is used in g(x), and would I have to make these functions non continuous as well i.e -1/x in the naturals, 0 otherwise?

Comment: There's no problem if $h(x)=g(x)$ for some values of $x$. In fact, for the purpose of the theorem, it would be ok even if $h=g$ but, of course, if you *already knew* that $g(x)\to0$, then you would not be attempting to prove it. If you are skeptical on this choice, let me give you a similar example: $g(x)=\frac1x \sin x$. The natural way to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\sin x=0$ is using your theorem with $h(x)=\frac1x$ and $f(x)=-\frac1x$. Notice that, though it might not look like it, $\frac1x\sin x$ is frequently $=\frac1x$: more precisely, when $x=\left(2k+\frac12\right)\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\forall x\in(0,+\infty)$$

$ f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\implies$

$$\forall x\in(0,+\infty)\;\; 0\leq f(x)\leq \frac 1x$$

$$\implies 0\leq \lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)\leq \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac 1x =0$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$$